# SPWebConfigModification error "The '[' character, hexadecimal value 0x5B, cannot be included in a name. Line 2, position 2727."

Tags: spwebconfigmodification

I am using SPWebConfigModification thorugh webapplication feature everytime it shows error "`The '[' character, hexadecimal value 0x5B, cannot be included in a name. Line 2, position 2727.`" I am very puzzled with this error. I have tried every possible solution given in Google with no help.The code I am using is given below: I am using a feature receiver.

```
[Guid("c35d2a13-980c-4afb-a832-26d9f7cec85f")]
public class WebConfigMod2EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{
    // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised after a feature has been activated.

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        string Name = null;
        string value = null;
        string Owner = null;
        string Path = null;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWebApplication spWebApplication = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
                Removemodifications(spWebApplication);
                SPWebConfigModification myModification = new SPWebConfigModification();
                myModification.Path = "configuration";
                myModification.Name = "Location[@name='Test']";
                myModification.Sequence = 0;
                myModification.Owner = "Moumita";
                myModification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureSection;
                myModification.Value = "<location path='Test'></location>";
                spWebApplication.WebConfigModifications.Add(myModification);
                spWebApplication.Update();
                spWebApplication.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised before a feature is deactivated.

    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            SPWebApplication spWebApplication = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
            Removemodifications(spWebApplication);
            spWebApplication.Update();
            spWebApplication.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
    public void Removemodifications(SPWebApplication webApp)
    {
        try
        {
            Collection<SPWebConfigModification> spWebConfigModifications = webApp.WebConfigModifications;
            SPWebConfigModification spWebConfigModificationToRemove = null;
            foreach (var spWebConfigModification in spWebConfigModifications)
            {
                if (spWebConfigModification.Name == "Location[@name='Test']" && spWebConfigModification.Path == "configuration")
                {
                    spWebConfigModificationToRemove = spWebConfigModification;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (spWebConfigModificationToRemove != null)
            {
                webApp.WebConfigModifications.Remove(spWebConfigModificationToRemove);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Please help me asap

Comment: have you tried this http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2008/01/05/spwebconfigmodifications-top-6-issues/

Comment: Tried everything. Is there any issue with my code.Even I tried to do it through Powershell and I came up with the same issue.

Comment: the blog is talking about the name paramenter.did you try to add using within contructor?

Comment: Hi @WaqasSarwarMCSE, I have provided my code above..Can you please let me know if I had done any mistake? or there is some other issue.